`await asyncio.sleep(0)` isn't concurrent with `loop.run_in_executor()`
await loop.run_in_executor(executor, open_read) wont return untill await asyncio.shield(get_audio_async(sentance)) yields control to the event loop. I put in the await asyncio.sleep(0) calls to no avail. Any ideas?
async def read_from_fifo(loop):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
    def open_read():
        with open('/tmp/fifo', "rb") as fifo:
            bytes = fifo.read()
            return bytes.decode('utf-8')

    while True:
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, open_read)
        if not data: continue
        message = DecodeMessage(data)
        yield message


async def play_audio(sentances):
    ...
    try:
        for sentance in sentances:
            audio = await asyncio.shield(get_audio_async(sentance))
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            audio_server.write(audio)    
            await asyncio.sleep(0)
            audio_server.write(sentance_pause)
            
        audio_server.drain()
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print("cancelling play_audio()")

async def main(): 
    async for message in read_from_fifo(loop):
        match message:
            case {"method": "narrate_from_cursor", "params":{"buffer": buffer, "cursor_byte_offset":cursor_byte_offset}}:
                ...
                running_task = asyncio.create_task(play_audio(sentances))

            case {"method": "cancel"}:
                if running_task is not None:
                    running_task.cancel()
                    audio_server.flush()



WHat is  get_audio_async ?  Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - we don't even know what are you using for audio, so that people can check the docs.

await asyncio.sleep(0) was yielding control.
I just had to yield enough times
await asyncio.sleep(0)
await asyncio.sleep(0)
await asyncio.sleep(0)
await asyncio.sleep(0)

to before run_in_executor(executor, open_read) would return.
When a message is read, I want that fully processed before I yield back to the play_audio(). For now it's good enough to use run_in_executor() so that the blocking audio_server.write call doesn't hog the concurrency
for i in range(0, stop, step):
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    await loop.run_in_executor(None, audio_server.write, audio[i:i+step]) 

